# Any idea why my flamingo plant is dying?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis

I've had a flamingo plant for about 6 months and recently most of the leaves discoloured and fell off and it looks like the others are going to follow suit. The root of the stems are all discolouring now as well.
Can anyone suggest why this may be? Typically I water it when the soil is dry up to the tip of my finger. I've had it in the corner of a bright room, but recently moved it to the window sill in the hope that would help but it doesn't appear to.

My only thought is over watering resulting in root root and I'm down to hoping that leaving it to dry out for longer will spur it's growth again.

Anyone have any other suggestions or ideas?

[image: sad flower]

Comment: Anthurium are florist plants - code for don't try this at home. They need more light but much cooler than most can provide unless you live at high altitudes. No South exposure. Water less.